# How to print raw byte content from a byte[] array to stdout in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing the same project as describe here:

[Wrap deflated data in gzip format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105481/wrap-deflated-data-in-gzip-format)

My problem is that when I try to print out bytes, I get weird results. My problems occur in the following code(Sorry for my bad choice of variables):

```
    for(int k = 0; k < head.length; k++){
        System.out.write(head[k]);
    }

    for(int m = 0; m < a.size(); m++){
        int comprlength = a.get(m).getclength();
        for(int ii = 0; ii < comprlength; ii++){
            System.out.write(a.get(m).getcompr()[ii]);
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < f1.length; j++){
        System.out.write(f1[j]);
    }
    for(int ll = 0; ll < total_d.length; ll++){
        System.out.write(total_d[ll]);
    }
```

The last two for-loops do not print out the contents of the their byte arrays. Thus I get a unexpected end of file error when using gzip. The weird thing is that if I comment out the second for-loop block (the block with the variables m and ii), nothing gets printed out.

So how do I properly print out the contents of my byte arrays? Why does the first for-loop print out properly when the second for-loop is not commented and why does it not print anything if that second for-loop is commented?

EDIT:

To be more specific:

I want to write out the raw bytes. And I want to do it so that it is right after each other for every one of my byte arrays

Comment: If you use System.out.write you may need to flush the output stream by writing a '\n' character at the end of your code.

Answer (score 54):

Assuming your byte array is called **buf**:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buf));
```

Edit:
It sounds like what you really want to do is write your bytes to stdout, not print them. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html for the difference between printing to a stream and writing to it. Easiest way should be to call the write(byte[] b) method:

```
System.out.write(buf);
```

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: bytes are numbers, and I don't see why you couldn't print numbers to the console. That's what the above does.

Comment: But I want to print the raw bytes

Comment: Thanks man. I had come across PrintStream shortly before you suggested it. It does print out the way I want to. I also found a bug somewhere else in my code that was causing the weird behavior. Thanks again.

Comment: How do I flush stdout in buffer mode? (normally \n would do that)

Answer (score -3):

```
 /* There is an image / ic_launcher in the drawable folder for which I am making ByteArray   */



    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] mByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

/* here I am showing the raw data not in hexadecimal format */

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mByteArray));
```

I think this will help you guys!