# Read values from files in different folders

Tags: java

I would like to read the values into these folders:

```
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp:68000
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone3/temp:50000
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone5/temp:24900
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone7/temp:62000
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone8/temp:65000
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone9/temp:78000
```

I tested this code:

```
public void listFolders() throws IOException
    {
        File directory = new File("/sys/devices/virtual/thermal");

        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : fList)
        {
            if (file.isDirectory() && file.getName().startsWith("thermal_zone"))
            {
                File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
                for (File file1 : listFiles)
                {
                        byte[] fileBytes = null;
                        if (file1.exists())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file1.toPath());
                            }
                            catch (AccessDeniedException e)
                            {
                            }

                            if (fileBytes.length > 0)
                            {
                                System.out.println(">>>>> " + fileBytes);
                            }                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I get null result when I test the code.

Can you help me to fix the code?

Also can you help me to optimize the code for performance?

Comment: What you mean 'I get null'? Where? No files found or empty?

Comment: I just get empty result.

Comment: Try to run your code in debugger, this will give you more info where you are going wrong, i.e. if the directory has files, if the file is found, etc.

Comment: Your catch-block for the AccessDeniedException is empty. Provide a System.err-output there. the fileBytes-array would be still null if the code enters this catch block.

Comment: What java version are you using? Since java 7 there is the nio package which provides much more powerful filesystem tools

Comment: I use Java 8.  Can you show me some example for Java 8?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if (file1.isFile() && file.getName().startsWith("temp"))
```

Correct it to

```
if (file1.isFile() && file1.getName().startsWith("temp"))
```

Now you will see bytes printed.

Answer (score 2):

In this statement,

`if (file1.isFile() && file.getName().startsWith("temp"))`

after && use `file1.getName()`

Should work!!!

Also, it will print byte object's hashcode, not bytes, for that you need to iterate through array and print. [Look here for refernce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009695/how-to-print-out-the-contents-of-a-byte-array-in-java)

Eg : `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fileBytes))`

Comment: Thanks, one more question. How I can optimize the code for performance?