# com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError

Tags: java, file-permissions, jsch

Am trying to create a `folder(folderName) and two files(file1.txt,file2.txt)` in it.After creating folder and files, am updating its permissions.First update files' permissions then folder's.But when folder permission is getting called for update, exception is thrown.Even exception is thrown permission of the folder and files are updated properly.Please help me to find how I can prevent this Exception.

**Update1 :**
      `channelSftp.chmod(511, folder);`//commenting this line, works without exception but can't update permission of folder.

**Update2 :**
      `channelSftp.chmod(511, folder);`//this line is the problem even after removing all the lines and keeping this single line with folder creation code.Folder is created but exception comes after permission is updated.

WinSCP Screen :

[image]

Code :

```
        String depDir = "/BaicDirectory";
        System.out.println("Processing ........ starts");

        Session session = new FTPComponent().getSession("");
        Channel channel = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
        try
        {
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("session is alive:" + session.isConnected());
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            InputStream ftpLogIStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("file1.txt content".getBytes());
            InputStream processLogIStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("file2.txt content".getBytes());
            channelSftp.cd(depDir);
            String folder = "folderName";
            channelSftp.mkdir(folder);
            System.out.println("Folder is created");
            channelSftp.put(ftpLogIStream, depDir + "/" + folder + "/file1.txt");
            channelSftp.put(processLogIStream, depDir + "/" + folder + "/file2.txt");
            System.out.println("Files are created");
            channelSftp.cd(depDir + "/" + folder);
            channelSftp.chmod(511, "file1.txt");
            channelSftp.chmod(511, "file2.txt");
            System.out.println("Files permissons are updated");
            channelSftp.cd(depDir);
            System.out.println("Directory to main location");
```

> ```
>             channelSftp.chmod(511, folder);//commenting this works fine
> ```

```
            System.out.println("All SFTP actions are done:" + channelSftp.pwd());
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();         
        }
        finally
        {
            if (channelSftp != null)
            {
                channelSftp.disconnect();
            }
            if (channel != null)
            {
                channel.disconnect();
            }
            if (session != null)
            {
                System.out.println("session is alive:" + session.isConnected());
                session.disconnect();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After all statements ........ ends");
```

Output :

```
Processing ........ starts
session is alive:true
Folder is created
Files is created
Files permissons are updated
Directory to main location
session is alive:true
Failure
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(Unknown Source)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._setStat(Unknown Source)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.chmod(Unknown Source)
        at com.app.sftp.CLOWriteBack.main(CLOWriteBack.java:747)
After all statements ........ ends
```

**Update 3: WinSCP session debug 1 log**

```
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.555 Changing properties of "folderName" (No)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.555  - mode: "u+rwx-s,g+rwx-s,o+rwx-t"
> 2015-11-23 03:06:04.556 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 91, Number: 10759
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.556 Sent 95 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.556 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.556 Read 4 bytes (24 pending)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.556 Read 24 bytes (0 pending)
< 2015-11-23 03:06:04.556 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 10500
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.556 Discarding reserved response
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.556 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.557 Detected network event
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.557 Received 41 bytes (0)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.557 Read 4 bytes (37 pending)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.557 Read 37 bytes (0 pending)
< 2015-11-23 03:06:04.557 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 10759
> 2015-11-23 03:06:04.557 Type: SSH_FXP_SETSTAT, Size: 99, Number: 11017
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.557 Sent 103 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.557 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.557 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.558 Detected network event
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.558 Received 28 bytes (0)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.558 Read 4 bytes (24 pending)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.558 Read 24 bytes (0 pending)
< 2015-11-23 03:06:04.558 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 11017
< 2015-11-23 03:06:04.558 Status code: 0
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.559 Listing directory "/BaicDirectory".
> 2015-11-23 03:06:04.559 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 80, Number: 11275
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.559 Sent 84 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.559 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.559 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.560 Detected network event
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.560 Received 17 bytes (0)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.560 Read 4 bytes (13 pending)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.560 Read 13 bytes (0 pending)
< 2015-11-23 03:06:04.560 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 11275
> 2015-11-23 03:06:04.560 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 11532
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.560 Sent 17 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.560 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.560 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.561 Detected network event
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.561 Received 327 bytes (0)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.561 Read 4 bytes (323 pending)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.561 Read 323 bytes (0 pending)
< 2015-11-23 03:06:04.561 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 323, Number: 11532
> 2015-11-23 03:06:04.561 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 11788
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.561 Sent 17 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.561 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.561 Read file '.' from listing
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Read file '..' from listing
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Read file 'folderName' from listing
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Waiting for another 4 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Detected network event
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Received 32 bytes (0)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Read 4 bytes (28 pending)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Read 28 bytes (0 pending)
< 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 11788
< 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Status code: 1
> 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 12036
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 Sent 17 bytes
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 There are 0 bytes remaining in the send buffer
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 ..;d;1024;2015-11-20T13:34:34.000Z;"useracid" [24416];"useracid" [8481];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.562 folderName;d;96;2015-11-21T08:47:52.000Z;"useracid" [24416];"useracid" [8481];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.573 Session upkeep
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.573 Detected network event
. 2015-11-23 03:06:04.573 Received 28 bytes (0)
. 2015-11-23 03:06:05.025 Session upkeep
```

Comment: Can you change the permissions in WinSCP?

Comment: Using same credentials am able to update permission without any issue.

Comment: Changing permissions of files (file1.txt and file2.txt) works, correct?

Comment: And in WinSCP you can change the permissions of both the files and the folder, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct am able to do that.

Comment: Can you append WinSCP session log file on level Debug 1 showing how you change (non-recusively) the permissions of the `/BaicDirectory/folderName`

Comment: Thanks for your response,Please check udpate 3 for session log details.

Comment: I tried to change permission from 755 to 777.

Comment: Hmm, nothing interesting in the log. I do not see any other way than to compare byte by byte the requests sent by WinSCP and JSch. If you want to try this, modify JSch `IO.put(Packet)` method to dump the `p.buffer.buffer` to console/log file. See for example [How to print raw byte content from a byte array to stdout in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14009709/850848) For WinSCP, please attach a log file on level Debug 2. And can you check in WinSCP status bar, what version of SFTP it uses? There's a label saying something like "SFTP-3".

Comment: Thanks for your valuable insights, I will try this.